# Генерация случайных чисел в диапазоне [a,b]

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Подскажите алгоритм, который выводит случайные числа в диапазоне [a,b]

Comment: a, b - целые или вещественные? Случайные числа должны располагаться на отрезке дискретно? Или нет? Ес-но с возможными ограничениями на тип данных.

Comment: натуральные числа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rand() % (b - a + 1) + a
```

Comment: Более правильный вариант, на мой взгляд -  `(double)rand() * (b-a) / RAND_MAX + a`
А еще лучше использовать не rand(), а более качественные ГСЧ.

Comment: нужно было именно то, что было предоставлено =)

Comment: qwerty12359: то что было представлено работает до тех пор, пока b - a < RAND_MAX (и то распределение не будет равномерным).

Comment: мне были нужны именно малые отрезки не превищающие RAND_MAX

Comment: Данный способ обрезки дает неравномерное распределение!

Comment: @gbg: **Любой** stateless способ перевода одного целочисленного диапазона в другой целочисленныйо диапазон дает заведомо неравномерное распределение, если длины диапазонов не являются кратными. Это считается само собой разумеющимся. Если целевой диапазон намного короче исходного, то получаемая неравномерность будет пренебрежимо малой.

Answer (score 5):

Так как функция `rand` устарела начиная с С++11 (у нее плохие характеристики), то сейчас лучше использовать классы из `<random>`:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device random_device; // Источник энтропии.
    std::mt19937 generator(random_device()); // Генератор случайных чисел.
    // (Здесь берется одно инициализирующее значение, можно брать больше)

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(10, 20); // Равномерное распределение [10, 20]

    int x = distribution(generator); // Случайное число.
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Так же в библиотеке `boost` присутствует свой `random`

```
boost::random::mt19937 rng;         // генерирует случайные значения
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> six(10,20); // Равномерное распределение [10, 20]
int x = six(rng);  // Случайное число.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    random_device random_device;
    mt19937 generator(random_device());

    int in1;
    cout << "in1 = ";
    cin >> in1;
    
    int in2;
    cout << "in2 = ";
    cin >> in2;
    
    uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(in1, in2);

    int x = distribution(generator);
    cout << x << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Готовый пример:

```
int random (int min, int max)
{
    max++;
    return abs(rand()%(max-min))+min;
}
```

Comment: И чем это отличается от принятого ответа?