# Генерация случайного числа в заданном диапазоне C++

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 mersenne(rd());
// в Функции же написано:
uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, n);
int i = distrib(mersenne());
int j = distrib(mersenne());
```

Я просто хочу сгенерировать число в диапазоне от [1; n]. Использовать нужно новые ГПСЧ из C++.

Xcode пишет:

> No matching function for call to object of type 'uniform_int_distribution<>'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно это написать.
Пробовал так же писать как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/41317/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-a-b), но Xcode выводит следующее:

> Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это не новые случайные числа уже 9 лед как вот пример из доки
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
 
int main()
{
    // Seed with a real random value, if available
    std::random_device r;
 
    // Choose a random mean between 1 and 6
    std::default_random_engine e1(r());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 6);
    int mean = uniform_dist(e1);
    std::cout << "Randomly-chosen mean: " << mean << '\n';
 
    // Generate a normal distribution around that mean
    std::seed_seq seed2{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()}; 
    std::mt19937 e2(seed2);
    std::normal_distribution<> normal_dist(mean, 2);
 
    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
        ++hist[std::round(normal_dist(e2))];
    }
    std::cout << "Normal distribution around " << mean << ":\n";
    for (auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: А разве я не пишу точно так же? `uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, n);`, только тут `std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 6);`

Comment: @haskiindahouse нет у тя не int нет потом ещё лишние скобки стоят в distrib, используй ctrl+c -> ctrl+v

Comment: Спасибо большое!